# Вылетает на рекурсии

Tags: ассемблер, память, рекурсия, masm32, masm

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста почему у меня программа повисает на "`invoke HeapSize`"?
То есть программа работает так :

> `Start{HeapCreate,HeapAlloc}` -> `recursive{HeapSize,HeapReAlloc}` ->
>   `recursive{HeapSize и на нём же завис}`

```
;Не большие пояснения -->
;ebp хранит в себе значение вернувшееся от HeapAlloc
;[ebp] и [ebp+4], после инициализации в start'е больше не изменяются

Recursive proc

    invoke HeapSize, dword ptr[ebp], HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, dword ptr[ebp+4]
    add eax, 4
    invoke HeapReAlloc, dword ptr[ebp], HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dword ptr[ebp+4], eax
    ...
    pusha
    invoke Recursive
    popa
    ...
    ret

Recursive endp


start:

    invoke HeapCreate, 0, 0, 1000
    mov ebx,eax
    invoke HeapAlloc, eax, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 595
    mov dword ptr[eax], ebx
    mov dword ptr[eax+4], eax
    mov ebp, eax
            ...
    pusha
        invoke Recursive
    popa

end start
```

**

### UPD 1 :

**

Вот регистры когда всё хорошо(первый HeapSize)...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот это уже когда второй HeapSize, программа виснет(paused) внутри Ntdll'а ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**

### UPD 2 :

**

```
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc

.data
    szCurrDrive db "A:\\",0

.code

    RecursiveSearch proc ptmemory:DWORD
        mov ebp, ptmemory

        inc dword ptr[ebp+12]
        invoke HeapSize, dword ptr[ebp], HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, dword ptr[ebp+4]
        add eax, 4
        invoke HeapReAlloc, dword ptr[ebp], HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dword ptr[ebp+4], eax

        push "*"
        mov eax, esp
        mov edx, ebp
        add ebp, 16
        invoke lstrcat, ebp, eax
        pop edx

        mov edx, ebp
        add edx, 261
        invoke FindFirstFile, ebp, edx

        sub ebp, 16

        push eax
        mov eax, 4
        mul dword ptr[ebp+12]
        add eax, ebp
        add eax, 595
        pop ebx
        mov dword ptr[eax],ebx
        push eax ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        mov edx, ebp
        add edx, 16
        push edx
        invoke lstrlen, edx
        pop edx
        add eax, edx
        mov byte ptr[eax-1],0
        push eax ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        pop eax
        push eax
        .if dword ptr[eax]==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
            ret
        .endif

        .REPEAT
            mov ecx, ebp
            add ecx, 321
            push "."
            mov eax, esp
            invoke lstrcmp, eax, ecx
            pop ecx
            push eax

            mov ecx, ebp
            add ecx, 321
            push ".."
            mov eax, esp
            mov ebx, edx
            invoke lstrcmp, eax, ecx
            pop ecx

            pop ebx
            .if ((eax!=0)&&(ebx!=0))

                mov ecx, ebp
                add ecx, 321
                push ecx
                mov ecx, ebp
                add ecx, 16
                push ecx
                call lstrcat 

                .if(dword ptr[ebp+277]==FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                    push "\\"
                    mov ebx, esp
                    mov eax, ebp
                    add eax, 16
                    invoke lstrcat, eax, ebx
                    pop ecx
                    mov eax, ebp
                    add eax, 16

                    pusha
                    invoke RecursiveSearch, ebp
                    popa
                .else
                    nop
                    nop
                    nop
                    nop
                    nop
                .endif
            .endif
            pop eax ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            mov byte ptr[eax-1],0

            pop eax
            push eax
            mov ebx,ebp
            add ebx,277
            invoke FindNextFile, [eax], ebx
        .UNTIL al==0h

        pop ebx ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        invoke FindClose, [ebx]

        ret
    RecursiveSearch endp

    start:
        invoke HeapCreate, 0, 0, 1000
        mov ebx,eax
        invoke HeapAlloc, eax, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 595
        mov dword ptr[eax], ebx
        mov dword ptr[eax+4], eax
        mov ebp, eax
        invoke GetLogicalDrives
        xor edx,edx
        .WHILE edx < 26
            mov ebx, eax
            and ebx, 1
            .if bl == 1
                pusha
                mov eax, ebp
                add eax, 16
                invoke lstrcpy, eax, addr(szCurrDrive)
                invoke RecursiveSearch, ebp
                popa
            .endif
            inc edx
            shr eax,1
            inc [szCurrDrive]
        .ENDW
        exit
    end start
end main
```

Comment: каждый раз, когда Вы пишете рекурсию, предусматривайте выход из нее. В Вашем коде такого нет и скорее всего упираетесь в размер стека.

Comment: И какой смысл в функции, если она не принимает параметров и ничего не возвращает, что же она делает ... собственно почему рекурсия, а не цикл ...

Comment: @Mike ну тут происходит рекурсивный поиск файлов, я только саму суть выложил, чтобы ни кого не пугать огромным кол-вом кода

Comment: @KoVadim там есть условие и он выходит когда надо, ну тут происходит такая ситуация когда программа осматривает какую нибудь директорию всё ок, то-есть в "Recursive" выполняется цикл, когда встречается поддиректория, то программа заходит ещё в один "Recursive", выделяет ещё 4 байта в куче для нового `handle файла`, когда программа отработала с нужной поддиректорией, то она по идее выходит из своей рекурсии и продолжает основную. Ну вот как-то так

Comment: А что значит "зависает" ? Что бы зависнуть нужен некий бесконечный цикл. Сомневаюсь, что WinAPI функции виснут, они должны или вернуть результат или ошибку. А значит зависает все таки ваш код, но тогда вы под отладчиком должны видеть в каком месте. И все таки очень странно, что функции ничего не принимают и ничего не возвращают. где же они хранят текущее состояние поиска и куда складывают результаты. может они какие то структуры в памяти одни и те же используют и следующий вызов затирает там что то нужное предыдущему

Comment: @Mike я загрузил скрин, в момент зависания

Comment: Сразу скажу, что входные параметры HeapSize'а я перепроверил, указатели такие же как и на первом заходе

Comment: В текущем виде пример явно не воспроизводимый (см. [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). В коде в вопросе должно быть все, кроме собственно поиска файлов (т.е. сама структура рекурсивных вызовов должна быть, в том числе выход из рекурсии по условию).

Comment: @insolor добавил полностью весь код

Comment: А `push "\\"` что в стек кладет ? только косую черту или все таки с 0-терминатором ... И зачем перед тем как вызывать себя рекурсивно делаете `mov eax, ebp; add eax,16`, если регистр eax нигде далее не используется. Или он все таки используется, только я не вижу ? (Я же правильно понимаю, что HeapSize возвращает в eax размер)

Comment: И почему вы кстати не используете возвращаемое `HeapReAlloc` значение, она же может переместить блок данных в другое место и указатель на область памяти изменится. И вот этот новый указатель она как раз вернет, а вы продолжите работать со старым указателем !

Comment: @Mike он кладёт грубо говоря подстроку "//", затем получает на неё указатель и прикрепляет к другой строке (в нашем случае пути).

Comment: @Mike к сожалению компилятора под рукой нет, ближе к вечеру скажу

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Ну на счет строк я понял, с ними походу все ok. А вот значение realloc надо использовать ... хотя приводит ли именно это к описанной проблеме сказать сложно.

Comment: @Mike Кстати хороший вопрос зачем мне нужен этот указатель если я знаю смещение моей строки (пути). Но всё равно heapsize будет вылетать, блин что же за головоломка почему он именно в рекурсии вылетает, я пробовал два подряд сделать heapsize но всё отлично, а тут не как :(

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, хорошо что почти весь код добавили, плохо что *почти*. Все что у вас выше `.data` тоже не помешало бы.

Comment: @insolor всё, выложил

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, у меня падает при обращении по неправильному указателю внутри `FindNextFileW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче я вроде-бы понял в чём касяк, я не знаю как правильно это объяснить, но, в моём приведённом выше коде, при каждом заходе в какую нибудь директорию увеличивался `HEAP` и в самый конец (тютелька в тютельку) дописывался условно говоря новый `hfind` и почему то всё потом вылетало на любой функции связанной с работой `heap` (то-есть `heapsize` и `HeapRealloc`), но я уже всё перепробовал не чего не помогает и попробовал крч сделать небольшой отступ в конце, точнее от `hfind` до конца `heap`'a например 5 байт и представьте всё заработало, но не прямо уж всё, но по крайне мере до этого момент :D Так-что тема закрыта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]